# Use Azure Service Bus to produce RSS feed

Tags: azure, rss, azureservicebus, syndication, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm looking to have clients subscribe to topics on an Azure service bus using an RSS Reader.

I can't seem to find documentation on how I would begin to produce the feeds dynamically from the service bus

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Bus produces an ATOM feed all by itself at the root of the namespace, which is called 'Service Registry". It sits at  https://yournamespace.servicebus.windows.net and will quite likely show as empty when you go there with a browser.

To explore the namespace feed (which is a nested structure of ATOM feeds), you need to present a [SAS token with "Manage" access](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-shared-access-signature-authentication/) for the root of the namespace in the "Authorization" or "ServiceBusAuthorization" header of the HTTP GET request. The standard "RootManageSharedAccessKey" rule has that right.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // for connection string: 
            // Endpoint=sb://[[yournamespace]].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=[[key]]

             var tp = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "[[key]]");
            var token = tp.GetWebTokenAsync("http://[[yournamespace]].servicebus.windows.net/", string.Empty, true, TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(token);
        }
    }
```

Using the snippet above in a console app (using the SB NuGet package), you'll get the required token string to put into the HTTP header.

When I use that token in the HTTP "Authorization:" header with one of my namespaces in Fiddler's composer for a HTTPS GET on the root, I get

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Publicly Listed Services</title>
  <subtitle type="text">This is the list of publicly-listed services currently available.</subtitle>
  <id>uuid:f1ccc436-e5bb-47f7-b780-a7d06e942d51;id=843</id>
  <updated>2016-01-05T12:30:33Z</updated>
  <generator>Service Bus 1.1</generator>
  <entry>
    <id>uuid:f1ccc436-e5bb-47f7-b780-a7d06e942d51;id=844</id>
    <title type="text">democtrl</title>
    <updated>2016-01-05T12:30:34Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://clemensveu.servicebus.windows.net/democtrl"/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>uuid:f1ccc436-e5bb-47f7-b780-a7d06e942d51;id=845</id>
    <title type="text">hshsjsjshjshsjhsjhs</title>
    <updated>2016-01-05T12:30:34Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://clemensveu.servicebus.windows.net/hshsjsjshjshsjhsjhs"/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>uuid:f1ccc436-e5bb-47f7-b780-a7d06e942d51;id=846</id>
    <title type="text">iotev2</title>
    <updated>2016-01-05T12:30:34Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://clemensveu.servicebus.windows.net/iotev2"/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>uuid:f1ccc436-e5bb-47f7-b780-a7d06e942d51;id=847</id>
    <title type="text">samplequeue</title>
    <updated>2016-01-05T12:30:34Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://clemensveu.servicebus.windows.net/samplequeue"/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>uuid:f1ccc436-e5bb-47f7-b780-a7d06e942d51;id=848</id>
    <title type="text">stelemetryqueue</title>
    <updated>2016-01-05T12:30:34Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://clemensveu.servicebus.windows.net/stelemetryqueue"/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>uuid:f1ccc436-e5bb-47f7-b780-a7d06e942d51;id=849</id>
    <title type="text">testqueue</title>
    <updated>2016-01-05T12:30:34Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://clemensveu.servicebus.windows.net/testqueue"/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

and when following the link for testqueue (but with HTTPS to protect the token), I get

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>https://clemensveu.servicebus.windows.net/testqueue</id>
  <title type="text">testqueue</title>
  <published>2015-09-07T09:33:46Z</published>
  <updated>2015-09-07T09:34:17Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name>clemensveu</name>
  </author>
  <link rel="self" href="https://clemensveu.servicebus.windows.net/testqueue"/>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <QueueDescription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <LockDuration>PT30S</LockDuration>
      <MaxSizeInMegabytes>16384</MaxSizeInMegabytes>
      <RequiresDuplicateDetection>false</RequiresDuplicateDetection>
      <RequiresSession>false</RequiresSession>
      <DefaultMessageTimeToLive>P14D</DefaultMessageTimeToLive>
      <DeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration>false</DeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration>
      <DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow>PT10M</DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow>
      <MaxDeliveryCount>10</MaxDeliveryCount>
      <EnableBatchedOperations>true</EnableBatchedOperations>
      <SizeInBytes>1550</SizeInBytes>
      <MessageCount>5</MessageCount>
    </QueueDescription>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Comment: Excellent Answer, thank you.
How would one go about adding that feed to an RSS/Atom reader?

Comment: That depends on what you mean with "RSS/Atom reader". Do you mean a framework abstraction such as the WCF syndication API?

Comment: Something like http://feedreader.com/ - I'm probably missing something in my understanding

Comment: ok, so my return from fiddler composer doesn't show any public feeds, but i have 1 queue and one topic type on there.

all the return shows is:
`<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><title type="text">Publicly Listed Services</title><subtitle type="text">This is the list of publicly-listed services currently available.</subtitle><id>uuid:db1b688d-0d5f-4a7b-8f76-276fb4f334a9;id=19017</id><updated>2016-01-11T16:08:55Z</updated><generator>Service Bus 1.1</generator></feed>`

Comment: Did you create and add the token with a header as described?

Comment: Ok, i was being a fool and de-encoding the token before putting it in the auth header.  
How would I actually get to the content of the messages?

Comment: Ah, i have it - this is pretty much what I need, Thanks for your help - it was a great start:  
[service-bus-brokered-tutorial-rest](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-bus-brokered-tutorial-rest/)